# Spring on Android without Maven

Tags: android, spring, rest

I can use a Spring REST client on Android without using Maven. 
Can someone tell me or point to a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the [distribution](http://www.springsource.org/download/community?project=Spring%20for%20Android), which includes the jars.

Comment: Link is now invalid. Try this link instead: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/android/spring-android-rest-template/

Comment: @RonE There is no version 1.0.1.RELEASE there. Is it up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Download the below jar files from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-rest-template/1.0.1.RELEASE) and [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-core/1.0.1.RELEASE) then add them into libs folder.

- spring-android-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar

If you want to use MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter message converter in your code in order to read and write JSON using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) JSON Processor's ObjectMapper, add it's library.

Comment: @user1162647 I've changed the link but i dont now how should you download those file :(

Comment: what about spring-android-auth?

Comment: @Piotr if you mean jar file you can download it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-auth/1.0.1.RELEASE)